# Finding a string match in a column and editing its field in another column

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say I have a list of fields relating to a car where each field is a column header eg. , License Plate, Brand, Colour, Date of Purchase.

My aim is to enter a License Plate number (for simplicity lets make it 1) into a cell in another Worksheet and create a macro that looks at that cell, searches all of the values in the License Plate column in the other Worksheet to find a match, stores the row that match was found on and then edit another field in that row, lets say, updates the Date of Purchase of that particular car to the current time.

I am struggling to find a way to do this and storing .Range objects doesn't seem to work with the method I am thinking of which is to find the cell which matches the License plate and then add x to it's column value in the macro to now be selecting the Date of Purchase column however don't know how to achieve this.

I initially tried the Range.Find method and tried to manipulate the output Range object where it found the match to change the column value but that didn't seem to work seeing as the Range object is a string. I have also tried making a Dim as Cells which you seem to be able to manipulate the values but there doesn't seem to be a Cells.Find method.

Comment: I have updated the question thanks

Comment: People are looking more to see the actual code you tried, not a description of it.